# Determine whether the following statement is true or false:

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Determine whether the following statement is true or false:

If a function is continuous at a point, then it is differentiable at that point?

How can I prove this statement is FALS.

Comment: By providing a counter example.

Comment: [Weierstrass monster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is an extreme counterexample: continuous nowhere differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can show it is false being giving a counterexample. For example, take $|x|$. It is continuous at $0$, but not differentiable there.